# Can a plane be perpendicular in two other planes if those planes are not parallel to each other?

Tags: plane-geometry

I have to write equation of a plane which passes through a point and its perpendicular to 2 planes , but before I start solving  I was thinking if can a plane be perpendicular to two other planes , if those 2 others are not parallel to each other ( linearly dependent) ?

Comment: Ever heard of the [Cartesian coordinates in 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Three_dimensions)?

Comment: Could you explain a bit ?

Comment: Think of the planes XY, XZ, and YZ. They are all pairwise perpendicular, and no two of them are parallel.

Comment: I see I was viewing it as 2D , my bad , thank you .

Comment: but if it was 2d then it would be possible , right ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What would be possible? There are no planes in 2D, to begin with.

Comment: I meant to say wouldn't* be possible, isn't a sheet a 2d plane ?

Comment: OK, there is ***only one*** plane in 2D. Surely it wouldn't be perpendicular to any other plane, because there is no other plane.

Comment: I mean a 2d plane not a 2d plane in a 2d world , because yes there would be just one 2d plane in a 2d world but there can be infinity 2d planes in a 3d world

Comment: If you mean 2D planes in a 3D world, then we are back at my first comment. Yes it is possible that a plane is perpendicular to two other planes.

Comment: Yes I finally got it , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: take two perpendicular planes, and a third plane perpendicular to their intersection.

For instance: with an orthonormal basis in $\mathbf R^3$, the $(x\text{-}y)$, $(y\text{-}z)$ and $(x\text{-}z)$ planes.

Comment: Indeed, take any two non-parallel planes, and take a plane perpendicular to their intersection.

Comment: That's true, but I wanted to point the planes can be pairwise perpendicular.